# Inserting circles in a plot

Tags: plotting

How can we insert a circle with an arbitrary radius, thickness and color in an arbitrary position in a plot which is created either by a list or a function (`ListPlot` or `Plot`)?
[image]

Comment: Look up [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) and [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html). Something like: `ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, Epilog -> {Orange, Thick, Circle[center, radius], Circle[otherCenter, otherRadius]}]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) to control the size (in pixels). With @eyorble's example:

```
pts = {x,Cos[x]} /. Solve[{Cos[x] == Sin[x],0<x<2 \[Pi]}];
Plot[
    {Cos[x], Sin[x]},
    {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
    Epilog->{Red, Circle[pts[[1]], Offset[10]], Blue, Circle[pts[[2]],Offset[10]]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using the method MarcoB suggested in the comments, recreating the above plot is reasonably simple. Find the intersection points and plot circles around them:

```
pts = {x, Cos[x]} /. Solve[{Cos[x] == Sin[x], 0 < x < 2 π}];
plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Circle[pts[[1]], 0.2], Blue, Circle[pts[[2]], 0.3]}]
```

[image: Demonstration plot]

You'll notice the circles appear vertically elongated. If you wish to have precise circles on your output, you'll need to change either the `AspectRatio` of the plot, or plot the circles elongated to account for the `AspectRatio`. The former is pretty simple, but the latter is a little bit trickier so I have implemented it below:

```
plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Circle[pts[[1]], {1, ImageAspectRatio[plot]} 0.2], 
    Blue, Circle[pts[[2]], {1, ImageAspectRatio[plot]} 0.5]}]
```

[image: Demonstration plot with corrected circle aspect ratios.]

Note however that this `plot` depends on the previous output of `plot`, so you'll need to plot it without the adjusted circles at least once to get it started. There are ways to avoid that issue, but they mostly revolve around determining the image aspect ratio in some other way prior.

Answer (score 9):

`Inset` is another way to deal with the aspect ratio:

```
pts = {x, Cos[x]} /. Solve[{Cos[x] == Sin[x], 0 < x < 2 \[Pi]}];
plot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Epilog -> {
    Inset[Graphics@{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, pts[[1]], Center, Scaled[.25]],
    Inset[Graphics@{Blue,Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, pts[[2]], Center, Scaled[.25]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Far from as elegant as using code like other answers but if you are just trying to highlight the intersection, drawing tools is pretty quick (right click)

[image]